# Error desconocido

Tags: java, mybatis

Este son mis archivos XML:

-Cliente.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
    <sqlMap namespace="Cliente">
     <procedure id="listarcliente" resultClass="controller.Cliente">
        { call ListarClientes() }
       </procedure>
    </sqlMap>
```

-SqlMapConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN" "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>
   <settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>

   <transactionManager type="JDBC">
      <dataSource type="SIMPLE">

         <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cibertec2018"/>
         <property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
         <property name="JDBC.Password" value="mysql"/>

      </dataSource>
   </transactionManager>

   <sqlMap resource="Cliente.xml"/> 
</sqlMapConfig>
```

-Luego tengo un paquete llamado controller donde tengo mi clase java IbatisRead

```
package controller;

import com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient;
import com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class IbatisrRead {
    public static ArrayList<Cliente> Listado () throws IOException,SQLException{           
      // Recuperando informacion de archivo de configuracion
      Reader rd = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");
      // Establecer objeto para procesar instrucciones SQL
      SqlMapClient cmd = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(rd);
      // Cargar una lista con los datos de todos los clientes
      List <Cliente> MiLista = (List<Cliente>)
                            cmd.queryForList("Cliente.listarcliente", null);     
      return (ArrayList<Cliente>)MiLista;
  }
}
```

-Luego cree una clase de java

```
public class Cliente {
    private int idcliente;
    private String nombres;
    private String ciudad;
    private String sexo;
    private String telefono;
    private String fecha_nacimiento;

    public Cliente() {
    }

    public Cliente(int idcliente, String nombres, String ciudad, String sexo, String telefono, String fecha_nacimiento) {
        this.idcliente = idcliente;
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
    }

    public int getIdcliente() {
        return idcliente;
    }

    public void setIdcliente(int idcliente) {
        this.idcliente = idcliente;
    }

    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getFecha_nacimiento() {
        return fecha_nacimiento;
    }

    public void setFecha_nacimient(String fecha_nacimiento) {
        this.fecha_nacimiento = fecha_nacimiento;
    }



}
```

--- finalmente cree mi vista llamado a mi controlador y mi clase

```
<%@page import="controller.IbatisrRead"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page import="controller.Cliente" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Listado de productos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <% 
            IbatisrRead objRead = new IbatisrRead(); 
            ArrayList<Cliente> obj = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
            obj = objRead.Listado();  
        %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Listado de clientes</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th>IdCliente</th>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Ciudad</th>
                <th>Sexo</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <!-- iniciar recorrido-->

                    <% for(Cliente c: obj){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%=c.getIdcliente() %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%=c.getNombres() %>
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <%=c.getCiudad() %>
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <%=c.getSexo() %>
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <%=c.getTelefono()%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%=c.getFecha_nacimiento()%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#">Editar</a> | 
                            <a href="#" onclick="Confirmar(<%= c.getIdcliente()%>)">Eliminar</a> 
                        </td>
                    </tr> 
                    <%}%>

            </tbody>
        </table>
                <a href="NuevoRegistro.jsp" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar clientes</a>
                <a href="BuscarProducto.jsp" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar clientes</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    function Confirmar(id){

        if (confirm("¿Desea eliminar el registro " + id + "?")) {
            location.href = "/ExamenEL3/Delete.jsp?id=" + id;
        } 

    }

</script>
```

-- Mi error este : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has revisado los parámetros de salida de tu stored procedure? Ese error de ClassCastException me hace pensar que el problema está en algo que devuelve el propio stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se ve en trace, uno de los datos tu consulta es de tipo bigInteger y lo que se esperar es un long, por lo cual re sugiero que revises tu consulta y los tipos de datos de tu objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema (ClassCastException) te lo índica en ésta línea:

```
List <Cliente> MiLista = (List<Cliente>)
                            cmd.queryForList("Cliente.listarcliente", null);
```

En **cliente.xml** invocas un procedimiento almacenado llamado ListarClientes():

```
 { call ListarClientes() }
```

Tal vez deberías mostrar el código de ese procedimiento almacenado para tener más claro el por qué de tu problema.